# Cannot flag duplicate if no accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicate-questions

Go to: [Karma - Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966434/karma-chrome-failed-2-times-cannot-start-giving-up/42700178#42700178)

1. Flag
2. Duplicate
3. paste [Karma: cannot start chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366304/karma-cannot-start-chrome?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Result: `This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer`

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187827/should-questions-be-marked-as-duplicate-if-the-older-question-has-no-accepted-an marking a duplicate in this case should be possible.

Comment: The question you linked to refers to meta sites (including this one) where the rules are different and there is no limit on the dupe target.

Comment: This should be moved to Meta Stack Overflow.  The duplicate rules on meta are different than the main sites.

Answer (score 3):

No, according to [the post you link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187827/should-questions-be-marked-as-duplicate-if-the-older-question-has-no-accepted-an), there should be at least one upvoted answer. There isn't a (visible) answer at all on that post, so you can't close it as duplicate of the other one (your copy/paste answer there was deleted by a moderator).

If the answer on the newer question receives an upvote, you can vote to close the other way around.

Comment: Ok, I copy/pasted the answer because I couldn't flag it as duplicate. I'm still not convinced it was wrong to copy/paste it, since it can't be flagged as duplicate. Now only one question has an answer, and there is no clear connection between the two questions (you have to read comments or look at the linked menu, which I guess only more experienced stack overflow users do?)

Comment: The clear connection isn't useful in the absence of any answers. "Congratulations, someone else had this same problem but no-one helped. We're preventing answers being added to your question. Aren't we helpful?" Nope. Once either question gets an answer, close the other as a dupe regardless of time order.